# Provider Hosted App with SharePoint 2013 on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sharepoint-2013

There are pretty good information available on SharePoint and Azure out. But my requirement is to create Provider Hosted App on AWS. Is there a step by step guide to AWS - SharePoint? All the googled links has limited information or more with assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Why follow a step by step when there is a cloudformation

It's all covered in the official sharepoint on aws deployment doc
https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/microsoft/sharepoint/latest/doc/Microsoft_SharePoint_2013_on_AWS.pdf